# apt-get problem while installing , removing and updating

Tags: 12.04, apt, network-manager, uninstall, modem-manager

I tried to install ZTE's software for mobile broadband but it got error while installing itself.

Now I was ok with the `network-manager` which itself detects my USB modem. But, everytime while installing or removing or updating, I'm seeing this.

Actually here, I'm trying to remove `crossplatformui` which is part of ZTE: software:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove crossplatformui
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
 crossplatformui
 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
 1 not fully installed or removed.
 After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
 Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
 (Reading database ... 480896 files and directories currently installed.)
 Removing crossplatformui ...
 ztemtvcdromd: no process found
 dpkg: error processing crossplatformui (--remove):
   subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Errors were encountered while processing:
crossplatformui
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Can anyone help me how to remove that crossplatform?

And can anyone give me a simple idea to auto reconnect my USB modem to Internet?

Comment: try `sudo dpkg -P crossplatformui` for more info

Comment: it shows same thing as above i said

Comment: try this `sudo apt-get --purge remove crossplatformui*`

Comment: I get the same error again and again. how we get rid of this?

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this before, first off, `apt-get purge` isn't always the best way to remove a package (sometimes removes more than it's supposed to)

Secondly, you might want to try `sudo apt-get -f install` and then if it installs it again, use `sudo apt-get remove crossplatformui` afterward, if you use said commands.

Hope this helps.

cody.smith

Comment: no it doesnt reinstalls it and it shows same thing as above i mentioned.

Comment: I face the same problem but the solutions above did not work